# Android In-App Billing Tax

Tags: android, payment, billing, country, in-app

I've implemented in-app billing in our app. All is working well. However, we're asked if we could determine the exact tax on each purchase to be sent later to a server for **real-time tracking purposes**, and the sales report from Android Developer Console is only updated once a month (not entirely sure, as according to the information from the site, it's only delayed for 2 days), so that is not an option.

The problem is we're only able to retrieve the price without taxes through the in-app billing API (as also stated in the API documentation).

It seems that the tax charges are based on the country the user entered through the credit card information - and, of course, due to security issues, that cannot be retrieved as well.

Is there another way to determine from which country the user is purchasing from (i.e., the one from his/her credit card). Or better yet, is there a way to simply determine the tax on each purchase?

Comment: https://wallet.google.com/merchant - here you can see all purchases in near to real time. And about which tax are you talking? About 30% to google?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not so familiar with it. Does it have an API where we can easily get net revenues, **especially** tax and other fees? Say, for a particular day, week, month, etc.? (Or if it already provides some page to view these information?)

To answer your question, I was referring to the tax associated with purchase (not the transaction fee from Google).

Comment: I dont know about API, but you can see sales for every day/week/month in "Bussiness insights". Also you can download report in CSV format.

Comment: I've checked the business insights page. However, it does not include the taxes, I'm afraid.